# Given initial touch points, how can I calculate a radius for a circle containing these points on it's circumference?

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, geometry, computational-geometry

I implemented a UIView that draws an arc. I have it working with a set frame, but I want to have it so when the user starts drawing an arc I can quickly calculate a radius for the arc given the very initial touch points.

Say I collect 5 initial points, how can I calculate a radius for an arc that this line is starting to create?

Answer (score 2):

You can build a circle through three non-collinear points. Calculate values of three determinants:

```
D = |x1  y1  1|
    |x2  y2  1|
    |x3  y3  1|

Dx = |x1^2 + y1^2  y1  1|
     |x2^2 + y2^2  y2  1|
     |x3^2 + y3^2  y3  1|

Dy = |x1^2 + y1^2  x1  1|
     |x2^2 + y2^2  x2  1|
     |x3^2 + y3^2  x3  1|
```

Ready-to use formulae at [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Cartesian_coordinates).

For example, `D = x1 * (y2 - y3) + x2 * (y3 - y1) + x3 * (y1 - y2)`, and D=0 for extra case of collinear points (when circle doesn't exist)
Circle (arc) center coordinates are

```
Cx = - Dx / (2*D)
Cy =   Dy / (2*D)
```

Circle radius

```
  R = Sqrt((Cx-x1)^2 + (Cy-y1)^2)
```

If you want to use four and more points, these points might not lie on the same circle arc, and you would need some kind of circle fitting ([example](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/LeastSquaresFitting.pdf))

Answer (score 0):

MBo's answer was very close for me, but I had to reverse the signs of Cx and Cy. (My coordinate system was that of OpenGL, where the origin is in the bottom left corner).

[Here](http://www.abecedarical.com/zenosamples/zs_circle3pts.html)'s where you can find equations for finding the center and radius of the circle, given 3 points, as well as pseudo-code.