# how to find the center of rotation of a point in 2d space

Tags: math, geometry, 2d

I have a 2d point that rotates around some center of rotation other than the origin.

how can calculate the center of rotation given only the different positions of the point?

Comment: This should provide an answer - https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1414369/3301

Comment: thank you @JohnAlexiou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get wanted result, you need three points.

Having them as points at circumference, you can calculate center of circle.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29019090/given-initial-touch-points-how-can-i-calculate-a-radius-for-a-circle-containing/29026870#29026870) or get formulas from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Cartesian_coordinates_2)

```
D = |x1  y1  1|
    |x2  y2  1|
    |x3  y3  1|

Dx = |x1^2 + y1^2  y1  1|
     |x2^2 + y2^2  y2  1|
     |x3^2 + y3^2  y3  1|

Dy = |x1^2 + y1^2  x1  1|
     |x2^2 + y2^2  x2  1|
     |x3^2 + y3^2  x3  1|


D = x1 * (y2 - y3) + x2 * (y3 - y1) + x3 * (y1 - y2)
Dx = (x1^2 + y1^2) * (y2 - y3) + (x2^2 + y2^2) * (y3 - y1) + (x3^2 + y3^2) * (y1 - y2)
Dy = (x1^2 + y1^2) * (x2 - x3) + (x2^2 + y2^2) * (x3 - x1) + (x3^2 + y3^2) * (x1 - x2)
```

Center coordinates

```
Cx =  Dx / (2*D)
Cy =  - Dy / (2*D)
```

Comment: Technically this is considered a low-quality post because it references a URL. Consider editing the answer _in case wiki is not available in the future_ as obscure as this statement is.